# How can I change the default max length of string properties in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.1

By default convention, strings properties in an entity model that are not explicitly given a max length are set to `nvarchar(max)` in the database. We wish to override this convention and give strings a max length of `nvarchar(100)` if they are not already explicitly set otherwise.

I discovered the `PropertyMaxLengthConvention` built-in convention, which by its description and documentation would seem to be what I am looking for. However, it either doesn't work or I'm using it wrong or it just doesn't do what I think it does.

I've tried simply adding the convention:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new PropertyMaxLengthConvention(100));
```

Then I thought maybe the default one is already being used, so I tried removing it first:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PropertyMaxLengthConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new PropertyMaxLengthConvention(100));
```

I even tried explictly adding the convention before and after the default one:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.AddBefore<PropertyMaxLengthConvention>(new PropertyMaxLengthConvention(100));
modelBuilder.Conventions.AddAfter<PropertyMaxLengthConvention>(new PropertyMaxLengthConvention(100));
```

No joy. When I add migrations, the columns are still created as `nvarchar(max)`.

Is there a way to use that convention to do what I want? If not, can I write a custom convention that will default string properties to `nvarchar(100)` but will still allow me to explicitly set them to a different value including maxlength?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After tracking down the source code for the aforementioned convention, I discovered that it only sets the default max length for properties that are specified to have fixed length. (Bizarre!)

So I took the source code and modified it to create my own convention. Now string properties with unspecified max length will have a default max length instead of being nvarchar(max). The only downside is there doesn't appear to be a way to detect when the `IsMaxLength()` configuration is explicitly applied. So if I have a column that I do want to have created as nvarchar(max) I can't use `IsMaxLength()` to do it.

To address this, I created an extension method for StringPropertyConfiguration called `ForceMaxLength()` that configures the property with `HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue)` - ordinarily an invalid value, but one for which I can easily test in my custom convention. When I detect it, I simply set the MaxLength back to null and set the IsMaxLength to true and let the property configuration continue as normal.

Here's the custom convention:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace MyProject.CustomConventions
{
    public class CustomPropertyMaxLengthConvention : IConceptualModelConvention<EntityType>, IConceptualModelConvention<ComplexType>
    {
        private const int DefaultLength = 128;
        private readonly int length;
        public CustomPropertyMaxLengthConvention()
            : this(DefaultLength)
        {
        }
        public CustomPropertyMaxLengthConvention(int length)
        {
            if (length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", "Invalid Max Length Size");
            }
            this.length = length;
        }
        public virtual void Apply(EntityType item, DbModel model)
        {
            SetLength(item.DeclaredProperties);
        }
        public virtual void Apply(ComplexType item, DbModel model)
        {
            SetLength(item.Properties);
        }
        private void SetLength(IEnumerable<EdmProperty> properties)
        {
            foreach (EdmProperty current in properties)
            {
                if (current.IsPrimitiveType)
                {
                    if (current.PrimitiveType == PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(PrimitiveTypeKind.String))
                    {
                        SetStringDefaults(current);
                    }
                    if (current.PrimitiveType == PrimitiveType.GetEdmPrimitiveType(PrimitiveTypeKind.Binary))
                    {
                        SetBinaryDefaults(current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void SetStringDefaults(EdmProperty property)
        {
            if (property.IsUnicode == null)
            {
                property.IsUnicode = true;
            }
            SetBinaryDefaults(property);
        }
        private void SetBinaryDefaults(EdmProperty property)
        {

            if (property.MaxLength == int.MaxValue)
            {
                property.MaxLength = null;
                property.IsMaxLength = true;
            }
            else if (property.MaxLength == null || !property.IsMaxLength)
            {
                property.MaxLength = length;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the extension method:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration;

namespace MyProject.Model.Mapping
{
    public static class MappingExtensions
    {
        public static void ForceMaxLength(this StringPropertyConfiguration obj)
        {
            obj.HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how it's used:

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace MyProject.Model.Mapping
{
    public class MyEntityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
    {
        public MyEntityMap()
        {
            Property(v => v.StringValue).ForceMaxLength();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just

```
public class StringConventions : Convention
{
    public StringConventions()
    {
        this.Properties<string>().Configure(x => x.HasMaxLength(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In EF6 you can use a custom code first convention, but you will also need to have a way to specify nvarchar(max) data type to a string property. So, I came up with the following solution.

```
/// <summary>
/// Set this attribute to string property to have nvarchar(max) type for db table column.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class TextAttribute : Attribute
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Changes all string properties without System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength or
/// Text attributes to use string length 16 (i.e nvarchar(16) instead of nvarchar(max) by default).
/// Use TextAttribute to a property to have nvarchar(max) data type.
/// </summary>
public class StringLength16Convention : Convention
{
    public StringLength16Convention()
    {
        Properties<string>()
            .Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DatabaseGeneratedAttribute>().Any())
            .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(16));

        Properties()
            .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TextAttribute>().Any())
            .Configure(p => p.IsMaxLength());
    }
}

public class CoreContext : DbContext, ICoreContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Change string length default behavior.
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new StringLength16Convention());
    }
}


public class LogMessage
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }


    [StringLength(25)] // Explicit data length. Result data type is nvarchar(25)
    public string Computer { get; set; }

    //[StringLength(25)] // Implicit data length. Result data type is nvarchar(16)
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }

    [Text] // Explicit max data length. Result data type is nvarchar(max)
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```